# A good way to get a down vote is to provide a library–dependent answer when the question doesn't have a tag for that library

Tags: discussion, tags, comments, down-votes

There was a question about JavaScript, but I gave an answer with an example using jQuery and I got the comment:

> A good way to get a down vote is to provide a library-dependent answer when the question doesn't have a tag for that library.

Should I consider the comment? Is recommending something that is not tagged a bad thing? If not should I edit/delete my post?

Comment: Imagine an asker who, for whatever stupid reason, *can't* use jQuery. Will anything in your answer work for them?

Comment: I don't think you should delete your answer, given the OP doesn't tell any restriction at all, and your answer maybe correct (I don't know about JavaScript too much though). However, you can edit and add note that your answer requires jQuery. Remember, your answer is not only for OP, but also for future viewers.

Comment: No, I think the comment -- and the downvote -- is silly. Unless the OP specifically asked how to do it without jQuery, I don't see a problem. Heck, I've answered a question in a different *language* than the one it was tagged for, and got a couple of upvotes and an accept, and no downvotes ([provided a Perl solution to a PowerShell question because there didn't seem to be a good way to do it in PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17715700/1248365)). I guess I'm lucky your downvoter isn't active in my tags. :)

Comment: If I tracked the right question, so far the only upvoted answer has jQuery code too... And I must say, in many library-independent JS question jQuery answers are always there, as if jQuery were the only javascript code people is learning today

Comment: That commenter could do to find less negative ways to express criticism. I find that comment really tasteless, even if you did do something wrong (though I don't think you did).

Comment: I completely agree with Radiodef - except for the technical fact that Stack Overflow doesn't provide for critical commentary.

Comment: I did [the same](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/225077/revisions) @S.L.Barth :)

Comment: @hims056 I noticed. I feel confirmed in my editing choice :-)

Comment: BTW, it doesn't look like he actually downvoted, he just posted the comment. That answer has no downvotes, and it hasn't been edited so the downvote couldn't have been withdrawn.

Comment: @AdiInbar No one down voted my answer that's the best part :). I was just scared about getting down voted. He didn't do anything except commenting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question not being tagged with that library should not preclude you from giving an answer based on that library - provided you stay on topic and are clear about how the library solves the problem.

The OP may not be aware of the library, or may have heard about it but be unaware of its features. The only time you shouldn't do this is if they have specifically mentioned that they don't want answers based on that.

Of course - for your own sanity and rep score - you will want to make sure that your answer suits what was asked. Your peers will let you know pretty quickly if they think your answer is unacceptable.